# Find the rotation axis and angle of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$$A=\frac{1}{9}
\begin{pmatrix}
-7 & 4 & 4\\ 
4 & -1 & 8\\ 
4 & 8 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

How do I prove that A is a rotation ? How do I find the rotation axis and the rotation angle ?

Comment: As a start, find the eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: Can I prove that this is a rotation, because $det(A)=1$ ?

Comment: No. Lots of matrices have $\det A = 1$ without being rotations. See the answers below. Basically you need to check $A^T A = I$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have $A^T A = I$. Hence $A$ is a rotation. Since $\det A = 1$, it is proper.

By inspection, $A \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\2\end{bmatrix}$, which gives the axis of rotation.

Inspection also shows that $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ -5 \end{bmatrix}$ are orthogonal eigenvectors corresponding to the (repeated) eigenvalue $-1$. Hence we see that the rotation angle is $\pi$.

Explicitly, if we let $R = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & -1 & 4 \\ 2 & 0 & -5 \end{bmatrix}$, then  $R^{-1} = \frac{1}{405} \begin{bmatrix} 45 & 90 & 90 \\  162 & -81 & 0 \\ 18 & 36 & -45\end{bmatrix}$, and $R^{-1} A R = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$, from which we see that the rotation angle is $\pi$.

Comment: Could you explain how you get the eigenvector [2 4 -5] on the third line for repeated eigenvalue -1 as this is not a multiple of the original eigenvector [1 -1/2 0]? You then create a matrix of all 3 eigenvectors. What is the significance of this matrix?

Comment: @twa14: The axis of rotation was a lazy guess, when you look at $9(A-I)$ the first row is $(-16,4,4)$, I just tried the combo. $(1,2,2)$ and was lucky. The trace is $-1$ and so the sum of the two 'non one' eigenvalues is $-2$ and since both are part of a rotation both must be $-1$. Now look at $9(A+I)$. There are many possibilities, I chose $(2,-1,0)$ and the third must be orthogonal to the first two so after a little work I got the third.

Comment: The significance of the matrix of eigenvectors is that $A$ is diagonal with respect to that basis.

Comment: Many thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to find the rotation angle is to take the trace of the matrix, the sum of the diagonal elements. By Cameron Buie's answer this equals $1 + 2\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle of rotation. $\theta$ can then be determined up to sign which will depend on the orientation of the axis of rotation chosen.

For non-symmetric matrices, the axis of rotation [can be obtained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Conversion_from_and_to_axis%E2%80%93angle) from the skew-symmetric part of the rotation matrix, $S = .5(R-R^\mathrm{T})$;

Then if $S=(a_{ij})$, the rotation axis with magnitude $\sin\theta$ is $(a_{21},a_{02},a_{10})$.

Comment: +1, the only original answer, which after a computational verification  turns out to be true. Write the matrix associated to an arbitrary rotation given by a vector (axis, length the angle) and identify.

Comment: Does this method extend to n by n matrices?

Comment: Hi I want to take a look at the proof for Trace = 1+2 cos($\theta$), but it looks like difficult to find a well written proof. Do you have any book or link that you can post here?

Comment: Basically it follows from Cameron Buie's answer since Tr(AB)=Tr(BA) and therefore taking the trace of both sides of $$(\hat w\: v_2\: v_3)^TA(\hat w\: v_2\: v_3)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\0 & \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{array}\right),$$ we see that $$Tr((\hat w\: v_2\: v_3)^TA(\hat w\: v_2\: v_3)) = Tr((\hat w\: v_2\: v_3)^T(\hat w\: v_2\: v_3)A) = Tr(A)= 1+2\cos(\theta).$$

Comment: How does this prove that the matrix is a rotation?

Comment: What if the rotation is a half-turn? It seems this formula breaks down in this case.

Answer (score 8):

If a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ is a non-trivial rotation, then the set $\{x\in\Bbb R^3:T(x)=x\}$ will be the axis of rotation, since non-trivial rotation about an axis moves every point *except* the points on the axis. Also, if the determinant of $T$ isn't $1,$ then it isn't a rotation (why?), though you've already seen that $\det(A)=1$ in this case.

Here, we're working with the transformation $T(x)=Ax$, so the set $\{x\in\Bbb R^3:T(x)=x\}$ is just the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. If $A$ didn't *have* $1$ as an eigenvalue, we'd know it wasn't a rotation at all (in this case, it does have $1$ as an eigenvalue). If the eigenspace's dimension were greater than $1$, then either it'd be a reflection matrix (if dimension $2$), or the identity matrix (if dimension $3$). The latter is clearly not the case, so it's either a rotation matrix or a reflection matrix. However, if it were a reflection matrix, its determinant would be $-1,$ instead (why?), and so it is a rotation matrix.

---

**Side Note**: Given any two non-zero vectors $x,y$ in $\Bbb R^3$ with the angle from $x$ to $y$ being $\theta$, we may assume without loss of generality that $\theta$ is no less than $0$ radians and no more than $\pi$ radians. (Why?) Then we have the following formula (where $\cdot$ is the dot product): $$x\cdot y=\lVert x\rVert\lVert y\rVert\cos\theta\tag{1}$$

To see where $(1)$ comes from, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition).

---

In general, let's suppose we've been given some matrix $A$ corresponding to a rotation in $\Bbb R^3$, and that we want to find its angle of rotation. First, find a basis $\{w\}$ for the axis of rotation (found as above), let $x$ be any non-zero unit vector orthogonal (perpendicular) to $w$, let $y=Ax$. Then both $x$ and $y=Ax$ will be unit vectors. (Do you see why $y$ is a unit vector?), so formula $(1)$ yields the following alternate formula for our particular $x,y$: $$x\cdot y=\cos\theta\tag{$1'$}$$ Here, $\theta$ is the angle of rotation of $A$. (Do you see why?) From there, we can determine $\theta$. (Do you see why and how?)

Alternatively, start with $w$ (as above), normalize it to $\hat w$, and then determine an orthonormal basis $B=\{\hat w,v_2,v_3\}$ for $\Bbb R^3$ with the Gram-Schmidt process. Then $$(\hat w\: v_2\: v_3)^TA(\hat w\: v_2\: v_3)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\0 & \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{array}\right),$$ which gives us another way to find $\theta$.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram Alpha tells me there is an eigenspace with eigenvalue $-1$ generated by $(-2, 0, 1)$ and $(-2, 1, 0)$ and an eigenspace with eigenvalue $1$ generated by $(1, 2, 2)$. (You could do this by hand). The eigenspaces are orthogonal, so this is a rotation by 180 degrees about the axis $(1, 2, 2)$.

The problem is a little atypical, since if you rotate by any angle that's not an integer multiple of $\pi$ you will have complex eigenvalues.

Comment: (This answer should have said explicitly: if you just want to prove it's a rotation, then checking that it has orthonormal columns and determinant one is enough.)

Comment: okay thanks for the clear answer !

Comment: I believe the rotation is by a multiple of $\pi$?

Answer (score 2):

A rotation matrix has unit determinant.  Such a matrix that has all non-zero entries may be decomposed into three rotation matrices, each representing a rotation about an orthogonal coordinate axis.

Answer (score 1):

The document: [orthogonal matrices](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906003509/https://www2.bc.edu/%7Ereederma/Linalg17.pdf)
is an excellence reference for this problem.

The steps are as follows.

1. Show that the determinant is 1. Matrices with determinant -1 are
   reflections no rotations.
2. Find the eigenvalues.   The three eigenvalues of the matrix are $1,
   \text{e}^{-i \theta}$,  where $\theta$ is the angle of rotation.
3. find the eigenvector for the eigenvalue 1. This is the axis of
   rotation.

**Solution:**
That the determinant is 1 can be directly checked.

The eigenvalues are $\lambda=1, \pm 1$.
So the **angle of rotation is**  $0$.

The eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$ is
$(1/2,1,1)$. **This is the axis of rotation**.

Comment: You've miscalculated the eigenvalues, I'm afraid. If $1$ were a repeated eigenvalue, then the determinant would be $-1,$ instead.